# Transient Fault Handling with Azure database

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, enterprise-library

We are using [`ReliableSqlConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.windowsazure.transientfaulthandling.sqlazure.reliablesqlconnection(v=pandp.50).aspx) from `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling` to support transient fault handling for Azure database, we are on .NET 4.6.1. The thing is randomly we got exception:

> "Internal .Net Framework Data Provider error 6"

when trying to open connection with this class. `ReliableSqlConnection` does not support `async await`, but built-in transient fault handling with `ConnectRetryInterval` and `ConnectRetryCount` on ADO.NET 4.6.1 only support at connection level, not command level.

Is there any alternative for `ReliableSqlConnection` in order to supportat command level with `async await` and avoid the above exception.

We use Elastic Pool on Azure SQL with tier standard.

Comment: Unfortunately, outside of the improvements in ADO.NET 4.6.1 and Enterprise Library, our recommendation is to write your own retry logic. I have heard of other developers using [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly).