# Error: "Internal .Net Framework Data Provider error 6"

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure

I am currently encountering error:

> Internal .Net Framework Data Provider error 6

when my application calls an API. The API then retrieves data from Azure SQL. Any recommendations for this error?

I created a retry API call functionality on my application.

Expected is I update certain data in the database.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO! Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Internal .Net Framework Data Provider error 6 in SQL Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42027191/internal-net-framework-data-provider-error-6-in-sql-azure)

Comment: Possible duplicate: Can this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42027191/internal-net-framework-data-provider-error-6-in-sql-azure
or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37699649/transient-fault-handling-with-azure-database

Comment: Please show us the full error message.

Comment: @LeonYue only "Internal .Net Framework Data Provider error 6" message is return